# Converting models in Matlab/R to C++/Java

Tags: r, matlab

I would like to convert an ARIMA model developed in R using the `forecast` library to Java code. Note that I need to implement only the forecasting part. The fitting can be done in R itself. I am going to look at the `predict` function and translate it to Java code. I was just wondering if anyone else had been in a similar situation before and managed to successfully use a Java library for the same.

Along similar lines, and perhaps this is a more general question without a concrete answer; What is the best way to deal with situations where in model building can be done in Matlab/R but the prediction/forecasting needs to be done in Java/C++? Increasingly, I have been encountering such a situation over and over again. I guess you have to bite the bullet and write the code yourself and this is not generally as hard as writing the fitting/estimation yourself. Any advice on the topic would be helpful.

Comment: [PMML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language)
is (was?) supposed to answer that need:
generate statistical models with one software, 
and implement them in another.
R can export some PMML models,
but time series models are apparently missing
(they may be easy to add).
And you would have to find some Java/C++ library 
to use PMML models.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You write about 'R or Matlab' to 'C++ or Java'. This gives 2 x 2 choices which is too many degrees of freedom for my taste. So allow me to concentrate on C++ as the target.

Let's consider a simpler case:  Prototyping in [R](http://www.r-project.org), and deploying in C++.  If and when the [R](http://www.r-project.org) package you use is actually implemented in C or C++, this becomes pretty easy.  You "merely" need to disentangle the routine you are after from its other dependencies (header files, defines, data structures, ...) and provide it with the data and parameters needed.  I have done that in the past for production systems.

Here, you talk about the [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/package=forecast) package. This happens to depend on the [RcppArmadillo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo) package which itself brings the nice [Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) C++ library to [R](http://www.r-project.org).  So chances are you can in fact re-write this as a self-contained unit.

[Armadillo](http://arma.sf.net) is also interesting when you want to port Matlab to C++ as it is written to help with exactly that task in mind.  I have ported some relatively extensive Matlab code to C++ and reaped a substantial speed gain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is possible in R, but in Matlab you can interact with your Matlab code from Java - see http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html. This would enable you to leave all the forecasting code in Matlab and have e.g. an interface written in Java.

Alternatively, you might want to have predictive code written in Java so that you can produce a model and then distribute a program that uses the model without having a dependency on Matlab. The Matlab [compiler](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/compiler/) maybe be useful here, but I've never used it.

A final simple way of interacting messily between Matlab and Java would be (on linux) using [pseudoterminals](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pty) where you would have a pty/tty pair to interface Java and Matlab. In this case you would send data from Java to Matlab, and have Matlab return the forecasting results. I expect this would also work in R, but I don't know the syntax.

In general though, reimplementing the code is a decent solution and probably quicker than learning how to interface java+matlab or create Matlab libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Some further information on the answer given by Richante: Matlab has some *really* nice capabilities for interop with compiled languages such as C/C++, C#, and Java. In your particular case you might find the toolbox Matlab Builder JA to be particularly relevant. It allows you to export your Matlab code directly to Java, meaning you can directly call code that you've constructed during your model-building phase in Matlab from Java.

More information from the Mathworks [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/javabuilder/).

Answer (score 1):

I am also concerned with converting "R to Java" so will speak to that part.
As Vincent Zooneykind said in his comment - the PMML library in R makes sense for model export in general but "forecast" is not a supported library as of yet.

An alternative is to use something like https://www.opencpu.org/ to make a call to R from your java program.  It surfaces the R code on a http server.  Can then just call it with parameters as with a normal http call and return what is neede using java.net.HttpUrlConnection or a choice of http libraries available in Java.
Pros: Separation of concerns, no need to re-write the R code
Cons: Invoking an R server in your live process so need to make sure that is handled robustly